# SQL server ODBC connection for Active Directory user who doesn't log in to the windows

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008, odbc

Do you think it is possible to create a SQL server ODBC Connection for an active directory user who doesn't log in into the windows.

Ideally this type of users will be used in the batch process. So, Another person logs in and creates a batch process and runs it with another user.

Note: I dont want to create a SQL server authentication. Instead would like to use active directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, and I do it all the time.  (Not that I'm anywhere near alone in this, of course.)  AKA: ["Service Account."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739458%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

It's for Server 2003, but it works pretty much the same for newer Windows OSes too.

> ### Create a Service Account
>
> To create a service account in Active Directory
>
> 1. Open Administrative Tools, and then click Active Directory Users and Computers.
> 2. In the console tree, double-click the Domain node.
> 3. In the Details pane, right-click the organizational unit where you want to add the service account, point to New, and then click User.
> 4. In First name, type a first name for the service account.
> 5. In Last name, type a last name for the service account.
> 6. Modify Full name as desired.
> 7. In User logon name, type the name that the service account will log on with and, from the drop-down list, click the UPN suffix that must
>      be appended to the service account logon name (following the @
>      symbol). Click Next.
> 8. In Password and Confirm password, type a password for the service account.
> 9. Select the appropriate password options, and then click Next.
> 10. Click Finish to complete creating a service account.